# Copy assignment operator, vector

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-assignment

I have this vector that hold values (Not on the Heap!)

```
std::vector<Dish> menu;
```

I want to implement copy assignment operator like this:

```
    Restaurant &Restaurant::operator=(Restaurant &&other) {
    if (this == &other)
        return *this;
    open = other.open;

    menu = std::move(other.menu);
}
```

I get those error/warnings:

```
        ^
/Users/avivlevitzky/CLionProjects/SPL-Project-1/Restaurant.cpp:49:10: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::vector<Dish, std::__1::allocator<Dish> >::operator=' requested here
    menu = other.menu;
         ^
/Users/avivlevitzky/CLionProjects/SPL-Project-1/Dish.h:18:15: note: copy assignment operator of 'Dish' is implicitly deleted because field 'id' is of const-qualified type 'const int'
    const int id;
```

What's wrong??

Comment: What is wrong is you failed to provide a [mcve].  In it you probably have a const field in`Dish`.  In addition, your `operator=` appears frankly insane.

Comment: I fixed it a little bit, I do have a const field in Dish, what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

It's the move assignment, so move your objects:

```
open = std::move(other.open);
menu = std::move(other.menu);
```

`open` or `menu` probably don't allow to be copied, hence the error.

You don't need to clear `menu`, because you are replacing the content with another object.